# How can i use nightwatch with async/await functionality?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, nightwatch.js

i m using nightwatch testing framework to test some functionality of the `<input />`, and it fails on a race issue.

### What i need to test

1. Add a value to the input text: `xxxx`.
2. press `backspace` 4 times.
3. assert that the `input` has value `''`.

But i get that the `input` has value of `xx`:

**ERROR**: `Expected element <#inputElement> to have value equal: ""  - expected "equal ''" but got: "xx"`

```
    "type 4 chars and use backspace to clear the input": browser => {
    searchBox.waitForElementVisible("@input")
    .click("@input")
    .setValue("@input",'xxxx');
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        await browser.keys(browser.Keys.BACK_SPACE);
    }
    searchbox.expect.element("@input").value.to.equal("");

    searchbox.click("@input");
 searchbox.expect.element("@input").value.to.equal("");
 browser.end(); 
},
```

This leads to the conclusion, that the for loop is executed before the `input` gets cleared, and then moves forward to the assertion. I tried the same test with `async/await` but i have the same error again. Do i miss something ?

### I test it with async/await like so:

```
    "type 4 chars and use backspace to clear the input": async browser => {
    searchBox.waitForElementVisible("@input")
    .click("@input")
    .setValue("@input",'xxxx');
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        await browser.keys(browser.Keys.BACK_SPACE);
    }

    await searchbox.click("@input");
    await searchbox.expect.element("@input").value.to.equal("");
    await browser.end(); 
},
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to `await` the first line of code?

```
await searchBox.waitForElementVisible("@input")
.click("@input")
.setValue("@input",'xxxx');
```

I think it's backspacing four times in parallel with the characters being entered, and two of them are being entered after the last backspace is sent.